# How to display customer order history with order items

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am new to MVC and I want to add a function into my program where I have a page with customer details and with the past orders that they have placed. But on the page it must also display the order items belonging to that order like how they do on Amazon.

My Customer Details View

```
        <header class="panel-heading">
           Customer Details
        </header>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt style=" font-size: large; float:left">
                    Name:
                </dt>

                <dd style="font-size:large;margin-left:15px; float:left">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.customer_name)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.customer_surname)
                </dd>



                <dt style=" font-size: large; float:left">
                    Cellphone:

                </dt>

                <dd style="font-size:large;margin-left:15px; float:left">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.customer_cell)

                </dd>

                <dt style=" font-size: large; float:left">
                    Email:

                </dt>

                <dd style="font-size:large;margin-left:15px; float:left">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.customer_email)

                </dd>

                <dt style=" font-size: large; float:left">
                    Address:

                </dt>

                <dd style="font-size:large;margin-left:15px; float:left">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.customer_addressline1)<br />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.customer_addressline2)<br />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.customer_addressline3)
                </dd>

                <dt style=" font-size: large; float:left">
                    Join Date:

                </dt>

                <dd style="font-size:large;margin-left:15px; float:left">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.customer_join_date)

                </dd>


            </dl>
        </div>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Order Model

```
    public class ORDER
    {
         [DisplayName("Order ID")]
              public int OrderID { get; set; }
         [DisplayName("Customer ID")]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
         [DisplayName("Batch ID")]
        public Nullable<int> DeliveryID { get; set; }
         [DisplayName("Employee ID")]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
         [DisplayName("Date")]
         [DataType(DataType.Date)]
         [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public System.DateTime order_date { get; set; }
         [DisplayName("Time")]
 [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="{0:H:mm}",ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
        public System.DateTime order_time { get; set; }
         [DisplayName("Status")]
        public String order_status { get; set; }
         [DisplayName("Preferred Date")]
         [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public System.DateTime order_preffered_date { get; set; }


        public virtual DELIVERY DELIVERY { get; set; }
        public virtual CUSTOMER CUSTOMER { get; set; }
        public virtual EMPLOYEE EMPLOYEE { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ITEM_ORDER> ITEM_ORDER { get; set; }

    }
```

My Item_Order Model

```
  public class ITEM_ORDER
    {

        public int Item_OrderID { get; set; }
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
         [DisplayName("Quantity")]
         [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be greater than 0")]
        public int item_order_quantity { get; set; }

        public virtual ITEM ITEM { get; set; }
        public virtual ORDER ORDER { get; set; }
    }
```

Item_Order VM

```
public int? ID { get; set; }
public int OrderID { get; set; }
public int CustomerID { get; set; }
public int ItemID { get; set; }
[DisplayName("Quantity")]
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Quantity must be greater than 0")]
public int item_order_quantity { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Brand")]
public int ? SelectedBrand { get; set; }
 [Display(Name = "Description")]
public int SelectedItem { get; set; }
 public SelectList BrandList { get; set; }
 public SelectList ItemList { get; set; }
 public List<OrderVM> Orders { get; set; }
```

Comment: I understand what you want to achieve, but what is your question?

Comment: Do I need to use that ItemOrderVM?

Comment: I'd always recommend to use viewModel. Although it's not "needed" to make it work, it's needed if you want to write good code.

Comment: So how do I display items from my Item_Order in the Order for the specific customer in a table

Comment: It depends by how you populate your viewModel in your controller, for sure you'll have to iterate through the list (or lists) with a foreach loop in the razor view.

Comment: But I don't understand something... the last piece of code represent the ItemOrderVM class? if this is the case you have a List<ItemOrderVM> inside ItemOrderVM? This doesn't make much sense to me...

Comment: Sorry I removed, that was by mistake

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89086/discussion-between-matteo-sganzetta-and-michael-fung).

Answer (score 0):

You want to present a list of item, so you need to iterate through them, something like this:

```
<table id="orderTable">
    @foreach (var order in Model.Orders)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>@order.date</td>
           <td>@order.id</td>
           <td>@order.customerName</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

@Dan Beaulieu: that was solving the askers problem because he asked (in a comment) how to display items in the ordersList and that was the way I think... Anyway I extended the answer, but I cannot do more with the information provided

Comment: please add an explanation as to how this solves the askers problem. [answer]

Comment: Hi I am trying to display the order like above, but I must also see the items purchased within that order from the Item_Order model

Comment: So (depending by the structure of your OrderVM), you will have to make a nested loop or you could make a master-detail structure with ajax call to populate the OrderDetails table when clicking on the Order's row. This will depend by the design and UX you want

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, you have to add the model first, in this case: `@model ORDER`

then you have to go through each order and if you want to display it in a particular manner, you have to use `orderby` builtin function here is an example

```
@foreach(var order in Model.ORDER.OrderBy(u=>u.order_date )){ 

//HTML goes here


}
```